# joomla extension directory,Alternative

Tags: ajax, joomla

Is that any alternative,exists for Joomla extension directory?
finding extension on joomla extension directory (Powered by Moset Tree)
is not really easy and fast sometimes.
is that any other website exists with some better performance,may be AJAX enabled search and other features?

You know that how many technologies has been developed,(AJAX,HTML5,...)
So I think this website is a bit old to meet the 2013's web-development standards.

UPDATE: 
Joomla has finally integrated JED into Joomla's back-end and now you have a tab in back-end,install from web,it has a AJAX search feature too,and you can easily install and find your extension and this is what,I've been waiting for for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure as to why you feel the Joomla Extensions Directory lacks performance, is hard and slow. People have been using it for years to search for extensions that suit their needs for their website. It's not a supermarket where you will find better prices and more variety of products at. It's the core Directory for extension, so to answer you question simply:

No, you won't find other websites that are faster, have better performance, more feature and Ajax based searches.

Try using Google to search for something you need, such as "Joomla image slider extension" or use the categories the JED provide to narrow down your search.

Comment: Actually,Please note that time is money, and there all always a better way to solve a problem.and I think this system is not fast.and it's a directory it's old and we didn't want to create a new technology for it,we want to use the existing technologies.

Comment: Joomla has finally integrated JED into Joomla's back-end and now you have a tab in back-end,install from web,it has a AJAX search feature too,and you can easily install and find your extension and this is what,I've been waiting for for many years.